# Oracle sequences of characters?

Tags: oracle, sequence

In Oracle, we can create sequences of integers :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IDPassenger
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 15
/
```

Is it possible to do sequences of characters ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible:

> sequence, which is a database object from which multiple users may
>   generate unique integers

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) article

Comment: Erf :'( No way to cheat ? Like using the number generated as ASCII code or something ? ^^' EDIT : i found an idea with a sequence and the CHR function of PL/SQL.

Comment: You can try function I gave in this answer to convert value given by sequence to characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29816279/2553753